# UITableView contentOffset changes on drag

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scrollview

I have an UITableView and I want to hide a part of it's header (kind of pull to refresh). I did it with contentOffset and it works fine when the content is larger than the screen. It hides when needed and show when needed but when the content takes up less space than the screen, it changes the contentOffset from (0,50) to (0,25.5) every time I start to scroll. I think it i not related to my code because I commented out everything that had something to do with contentOffset except the viewWillAppear method what sets the contentOffset the first time. Any idea?

Comment: please add your code

Comment: I created a new project to test it out. The same thing happens... This is my TableViewController:

`class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.tableView.contentOffset  = CGPointMake(0, 50)
    }

}`
Here is my layout: [link](https://s32.postimg.org/rle7z1aol/Screen_Shot_2016_07_15_at_12_41_57.png) And here is the problem itself: [link](https://s32.postimg.org/hufebli8l/ezgif_com_video_to_gif.gif)

Comment: are you using storyboard?

Comment: Yes. I'm using storyboards

Comment: sorry for late, just added my answer

Answer (score 1):

On attribute inspector, unchecked `Adjust Scroll View Insets` as show in image below

[image]

Comment: It is an UITableViewController, there are no controllers. Unchecking that did solve it neither.

Comment: Sorry, *there are no constraits

Comment: Thank you so much! I read that you had to uncheck that on 1000 posts but I didn't know you had to remove the constraints too! Still, how do you solve this problem while also using constraints? I need them for the UI to look right.

Comment: @Gary Hi, i edited my answer. There is no need to remove the constraint. So, select your view controller on storyboard, uncheck that and add your constraints as usual

Comment: @xmhafiz I found that it works when all the constraints are correctly set, or when there are none. When some constraints are set and others are missing, it depends. For some constraints it doesn’t work when they are missing. In general I’d just advise to either not use any or lay the views out completely to avoid bugs. Thanks again.